# How do I get this Technical Details in my design

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting

I have been searching for methods to get a similar result where I can show the client the technical nuisances of my design.

I am trying to locate a script that would allow me to show the dimensions and angles of cut in my design in Illustrator.

I am aware of this option from [Adam](https://adamdehaven.com/blog/dimension-adobe-illustrator-designs-with-a-simple-script/) but it does not have the functions as show in the image.

Thank you for your help and advice.[image]

Comment: I think the only way to get those technical details is to add them yourself. A software will always struggle to know which measurements you'd want to show and which you wouldn't. Also, I think you meant [nuances](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/nuance) instead of [nuisances](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/nuisance?s=t).

Comment: Oops yes I meant nuances.....but you see its a nuisance that I am not able to tame into show the client the amount of hard work I put in and to make him understand my design. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I do think they *are* nuisances. Way too often, gridlines like these are added after the fact and function only to lend 'interestingness' to a design that otherwise lacks that attribute. In your example, I refuse to believe that '2x' is actually twice as wide as 'x' is, it's more like 3.5 times.

Comment: This is not my design. It is only a representation of what I want to achieve. The original link to the image is here - https://www.behance.net/gallery/46201443/Quanto

Comment: The work done by a designer to reach a maximum level of optimization of a logo design is usually of several tests and sketches (tens as minimum).

If you really are the one who has made this design I am surprised that you do not know its dimensions practically from memory. Unless it's a simple font with some arrangements and now you must find its measurements.

Comment: Nice design - but I remember from school that 1 2/4 is probably better expressed at 1 1/2 ;)

Comment: [x must equal "multiply by 1.5" and how is 2-1/4x *narrower* than 2x??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhS81.png) All the dimensioning and guides may look interesting *at first glance* but if they are *completely nonsensical* upon examination, they are really only there for visual interest.

Comment: @Scott true but then graphic designers sometimes try to sell such things to clients.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of technical stuff you should and actually must draw on your own as these are the values that you are showing, because it will not be possible to guess by others. So think it this way - if human can't guess values, software can't guess them either. Human writes software. Human should guess what should be done by the software that would guess what you want to show. Not possible.